# Small town cop TV show (70s?) where nuclear powered robot is disarmed

Tags: story-identification

There was a TV show of which I saw one episode.  Details are fuzzy, but it was a small town and there were two police officers.  Someone was demonstrating a new robot in town.  It had a TV for a belly.  It did useful things, but eventually it had some sort of internal meltdown and was going to explode.  (Probably some nuclear explosion?)  One of the cops is able to disconnect the battery at the exact second the robot is saying "Zeerroooooooooo---".

What show was this?

It was in color, if that's helpful.  I'm guessing 70s, perhaps early 80s.

Comment: If it were more recent I would have guessed maybe Eureka, but I don't think it could be confused for a show from the 70s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

CHiPS S06E11 - Day of the Robot

> Ponch and Bobby have fun with a robot assigned to their station—until it becomes a threat to their lives.

https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5vhhoi

[image: Robot]

[image: Cutting Wires]